# Resizing powerpoint slides and saving them as images with a certain naming scheme?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I found this awesome script that works great for what I need, but it has a few problems. Ive banged my head against it for the last 4 hours, trying to learn VB, and I just cant get it figured out.

I need a few things:

Images have to have a max width of 900px

The aspect ratio needs to be maintained

Images need to be saved following the naming scheme: "x01","x02","x03" and so on and so forth, with x being "sImageName". Basically just a leading zero on any slide number of 9 or less.

Bonus point if you know why you get an error when your un the macro for a second time, and try to select the same folder you chose the first time. Extra Bonus points if you know how I can only return Err_Prefixnull when nothing is input in the box instead of returning two error messages.

```
    Dim path As String
    path = GetSetting("FPPT", "Export", "Default Path")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = path
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select destination folder"
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            path = .SelectedItems(1)
            Save_PowerPoint_Slide_as_Images (path)
            MsgBox "Saving slides to " + path
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing was saved"
        End If
    End With

    If path <> "" Then
        'Open path For Output As #n
        SaveSetting "FPPT", "Export", "Default Path", path
    End If

End Sub

Sub Save_PowerPoint_Slide_as_Images(path As String)
    Dim sImagePath As String
    Dim sImageName As String
    Dim sPrefix As String
    Dim oSlide As Slide '* Slide Object
    Dim lScaleWidth As String  '* Scale Width
    Dim lScaleHeight As String '* Scale Height
    On Error GoTo Err_ImageSave
    
    Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
    Message = "Input an image prefix"    ' Set prompt.
    Title = "Prefix Selector"    ' Set title.
    Default = "a"    ' Set default.
    
    Dim ErrMessage
    ErrMessage = "A prefix must be input"    ' Set prompt.
    
    ' Display message, title, and default value.
    MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
    
   If MyValue.InputBox <> "" Then
    GoTo Err_Prefixnull
    End If
 
    sImagePath = path
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    sImageName = MyValue & oSlide.SlideIndex & ".jpg"
    oSlide.Export sImagePath & "\" & sImageName, "JPG"
    Next oSlide

Err_ImageSave:
    If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
    
Err_Prefixnull:
  ' Display message, title, and default value.
   MsgBox (ErrMessage)
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for resizing this code is:

The .Export can continue to be filled in with the dimensions of the export you wish for.

If you wanted 900 width, and have aspect ratio maintained, the code would be:

```
oSlide.Export sImagePath & "\" & sImageName, "JPG", "900"
```

When a height is not input, the code automatically keeps aspect ratio.

If you wanted 900 width, and 400 height, the code would be:

```
oSlide.Export sImagePath & "\" & sImageName, "JPG", "900", "400"
```

As for the naming scheme, the correct code is as follows:

```
sImageName = MyValue & Format(oSlide.SlideIndex, "00") & ".jpg"
```

This format will only affect double digit numbers, and when rolled over to a 3 digit number, naming is not affected, and the number will continue counting normally.